# MacBook M1 Graphics Driver for Ubuntu running on UTM?

Tags: drivers, graphics, macbook

Title says it all. I've been running ARM version of Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) on my M1 MacBook Air through UTM for learning purposes and it's been working great so far. Only problem is the crazy screen tearing from not using hardware supported graphics (just using the default llvmpipe) which isn't great to look at all the time.

And I saw that Asahi Linux has managed to reverse engineer a working version of the M1 graphics driver. So I'm asking if there is something for Ubuntu yet or if I could somehow use the M1 driver for Asahi Linux on Ubuntu.

Comment: "Not yet" is the answer to the first question, and the second is not something for the faint of heart. You can try to [implement the GPU drivers from source](https://github.com/AsahiLinux/linux/tree/asahi/drivers/gpu), but there are a number of dependencies and configuration details that would need to be tended to. There won't be a step-by-step for this anytime soon 